# Многопроцессорный парсер теряет ссылки при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, multiprocessing

Я хочу написать парсер для некоторого вебсайта, 
который имеет много JS кодов. Для этого я решил выбрать связку `Selenium`+`PhantomJS`+`lxml`. Работаю на Python.
Парсер необходим достаточно быстрый, чтобы обрабатывал не менее 1000 ссылок за 1 час. Для этой цели
я решил использовать многопроцессорность. (не многопоточночность - из-за GIL!). Для разбиения на процессы
использовал `concurrent.Future.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Проблема в следующем: я, например, даю на вход 10 
ссылок, на выходе обрабатывается в лучшем случае 9 
(может и 6). Это плохо! Есть еще некоторая зависимость
с увеличением количества потоков увеличивается количество
потерянных ссылок. Первое, что я решил сделать - это 
проследить, где идет обрыв программы, где она перестает
выполняться. (`assert` в моем случае на сколько я понял
не пойдет, из за многопроцессорности). Тут я определил
что обрыв идет в функции `browser.get(l)` - не загружает
страницу. Я попробовал добавить `time.sleep(x)`, потом
добавил `wait` видимый и не видимый. Тоже ничего не изменилось. Начал исследовать функцию `get()` из модуля 
`selenium`, нашел что она перезагружать с того же модуля
функцию `execute()`, и там я залез в дебри, что мои 
знания не позволяют разобраться, да и времени особо нет.
И в то же время, я попробовал запустить в один процесс.
То есть количество процессов = 1. И тоже одна ссылка 
потерялась. Это навело на мысль, что возможно дело не 
в `selenium`+`phantomJS`, а в `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Я заменил
этот модуль на `multiproessing.Pool` - и, о чудо, ссылки 
перестали теряться. Но вместо этого появилась другая
проблема, более 4 процессов не выполняет. Если ставишь
больше, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
File "interface.py", line 34, in hotline_to_mysql
    w = Parse_hotline().browser_manipulation(link)
File "/home/water/work/parsing/class_parser/parsing_classes.py", line 352, in browser_manipulation
    browser.get(l)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 247, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 471, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1210, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1185, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "interface.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
File "interface.py", line 63, in main
    executor.map(hotline_to_mysql, link_list)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Код:

```
import random
import time
import lxml.html as lh
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from concurrent.futures import Future, ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
AMOUNT_PROCESS = 5

def parse(h)->list:
    # h - str, html of page
    lxml_ = lh.document_fromstring(h)
    name = lxml_.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div[6]/ul/li[1]/a/@title')
    prices_ = (price.text_content().strip().replace('\xa0', ' ')
                for price in lxml_.xpath('//*[@id="gotoshop-price"]'))
    markets_ =(market.text_content().strip() for market in
            lxml_.find_class('cell shop-title'))
    wares = [[name[0], market, price] for (market, price)
            in zip(markets_, prices_)]
    return wares


def browser_manipulation(l):
    #options =  []
    #options.append('--load-images=false')
    #options.append('--proxy={}:{}'.format(host, port))
    #options.append('--proxy-type=http')
    #options.append('--user-agent={}'.format(user_agent)) #тут хедеры рандомно

    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    #user agent takes from my config.py
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (random.choice(USER_AGENT))
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    #print(browser)
    #print('~~~~~~', l)
    #browser.implicitly_wait(20)
    #browser.set_page_load_timeout(80)
    #time.sleep(2)
    browser.get(l)
    time.sleep(20)
    result = parse(browser.page_source)
    #print('++++++', result[0][0])
    browser.quit()
    return result

def main():
    #open some file with links

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        link_list = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in f]
    with Pool(AMOUNT_PROCESS) as executor:
        executor.map(browser_manipulation, link_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Собственно вопросы: где может быть ошибка? из-за 
селениума и фантома, `ProcessPoolExecutor`'a, или я где
то код написал не правильно?
Как можно увеличить скорость до 1000 ссылок в час?
Наконец, может есть какой то другой способ паринга 
динамических страниц? (само собой на питоне)

Comment: разве browser = webdriver.не запустит браузер физически? и зачем так делать многопоточно. Испольщуйте requests или urllib.request

Comment: browser = webdriver.PhantomJS() запускает физически процесс но не всегда он корректо выполняется до конца,  одну или несколько ссылок с десятка, не парсит. urllib.request - не отрабатывает js скрипты и ajax запросы.

Comment: смотрели http://www.devsplanet.com/question/35317188 или https://torina.top/main/163/

Comment: благодарю за ссылки, сегодня на работе пересмотрю их более детально)

Comment: А вы не думали использовать scrapy? Инструмент очень мощный, да и решение для парсинга динамических страниц я думаю там есть

Comment: В сторону (не имеет отношения к вопросу): lxml умеет GIL отпускать. Если (не вникал) phantomjs свои процессы запускает , то GIL опять таки не причём (GIL внутри одного питон процесса действует). При выполнении блокирующих I/O операций таких как сетевые запросы, питон отпускает GIL — то есть снова, даже если страницы питоном загружаются, GIL не препятствует параллельной загрузке.

Comment: По вопросу: убедитесь, что функция, передаваемая в пул, не выбрасывает исключения (в лог пишите все исключения). Попробуйте минимальный самодостаточный пример создать (например убрать phantomjs и использовать код-заглушку, который спит и случайно исключения может выбрасывать). [mcve]

Comment: rusnassonov - сильно не вникал, но scrapy плохо дружит с динамическими страницами, хотя встречал некоторые решения через WebKit -> PyQt и splash .. Благодарю за совет. 

jfs - да, вы правы - в тредпуле страници грузяться параллельно, через фантом. 
Благодарю за ссылку про минимальный, самодостаточный код...

Answer (score 1):

попробовал вместо ProcessPoolExecutor - ThreadPoolExecutor, ссылки терять перестал. И в данном случае, работает примерно на той же скорости что и Process. 
Впорос еще актуален, если есть мысли по поводу, буду благодарен.